# Computing the Hausdorff measure of line segments

Tags: calculus, geometry, measure-theory

Let $\lbrace e_1,e_2,e_3\rbrace$ be the standard basis on $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Let $I_1$ be the line segment between $e_1$ and $e_3$, $I_2$ the line segment between $0$ and $e_3$, $I_3$ the line segment between $e_2$ and $e_3$ and $T$ the triangle with vertices $0, e_1, e_2$.

Define $E:=I_1 \cup I_2 \cup I_3 \cup T$ with $E \subset \mathbb{R^3}$

How to compute the Hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H^2}(E)$ and conclude that dim$_\mathcal{H}(E)=2$?

I tried to use that there is a map $S: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ such that $S(E)=B_1(0)$ and $E=S^{-1}(B_1(0))$.

So $\mathcal{H^s}(E)=|$det$(T^{-1})|\mathcal{H^s}(B_1(0))$

Here I don't see how to continue and I'm not sure if it works.

How to proceed to compute the Haussdorf measure and getting the dimension with the standard Basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your triangle $T$ is a subset of the $xy$ plane. Its $2$ dimensional Hausdorff measure is just its area: $\dfrac 12$.

Likewise, the line segment $I_1$ lies in the $xz$ plane so its $1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure is its length: $\sqrt 2$. But $H^1(I_1) < \infty$ implies $H^2(I_1) = 0$. Likewise for $I_2$ and $I_3$. Then you get
$$\frac 12 = H^2(T) \le H^2(E) \le H^2(I_1) + H^2(I_2) + H^2(I_3) + H^2(T) = H^2(T) = \frac 12$$
so that $H^2(E) = \dfrac 12$.